# Iterate through JSON String in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, iteration

it seems to be a really easy question, but I am a little bit struggling: I am receiving a JSON String via JavaScript. Now I would like to iterate through the element. The resulting string has this form: `{"title":value,"title2":value}`

How can I iterate through this JSON string without knowing the key and value? I would like to get this output:

> title -> value

> title2 -> value2

I tried it this way:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$array = json_decode($json,true);
$response = "Test";
foreach($array as $key=>$val) {
    $response = $response. "$key : $val";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

It only returns "Test". If I change it to echo json_encode($array), it returns the mentioned JSON String.

Comment: wait, are you using php or javascript?  You mention both in your question.  I answered in php, but it is simple to do in js also

Comment: JavaScript as a sender and php as a receiver.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Have you tried to dump `$array`, just to see what it contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention javascript and php in your question, so I'm going to answer for both.  Here is JS, two different ways.  I believe that foreach is being deemphasized in favor of the (of) construct now, but I don't work primarily in JS:

```js
var json = '{"title": 12, "title2": "text"}';
var data = JSON.parse(json);

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key + ' -> ' + data[key])
})

for(key of Object.keys(data)) {
  console.log(key + ' -> ' + data[key]);
}
```

And for PHP:

You can parse the json string into an array using json_decode:

```
$json = '{"title": 12, "title2": "text"}';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
    echo "$key : $val";
}
```

true parses it into an array instead of a std object.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I added the code I used. Unfortanetly it does not enter the loop. Do you have any idea what might be wrong? Might it be an error because of the type? JSON_decode returns a string.

Comment: json_decode is bad in one way because it will fail silently.  You can call json_last_error() to get the last error and troubleshoot.  I would start by checking the value of $json, to make sure that it is valid json.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: json_decode returns a string, so it seems to fail.

Comment: You can also check the value of array with something like echo "<pre>"; print_r($array); echo "</pre>";  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($json); echo "</pre>"; exit;

Comment: What does json_decode return?  Does json_last_error show an error?  What does $array contain?

Comment: gettype($array) returns string.

Comment: It's hard for me to troubleshoot on my end, because when I execute `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');` I end up with an empty string in $json.  What do you get?

Comment: I would probably use var_dump($array) in troubleshooting. It will show both the type and the value in one operation.

Comment: If I execute it directly, I will also get an empty string. Is it possible to use var_dump if I execute it on another page (where the JavaScript is executed)? It throws an error if I would like to output the var dump result via json.

Comment: var_dump will only work in the context of the script that is executing.  If I understand what you are doing, you are attempting to use php://input to directly access the request body and read the string from it.  Can you tell me what the request body looks like?

Comment: The request payload showing in chrome network tools is {"title":value,"title2":value2}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235868/discussion-between-chris-strickland-and-javaforandroid).

Comment: The problem was caused by the JSON String. It was escaped and therefore not readable. It has to be in this format: '{" instead of "{' or "{\".

Answer (score 0):

Because of response's format you must decode the decoded format in order to take the object as you want

```
$json = '{"title": 12, "title2": "text"}';
$encoded=json_encode($json);
$decoded=json_decode($encoded);
$ddecode=json_decode($decoded);
foreach($ddecode as $key=>$val) {
    echo "$key -> $val";
}
```

Output :

```
title -> 12 title2 -> text
```